# New to Programming: Creating a kids adding game in python

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and having trouble with a problem I have for homework. Here is the homework problem:

Develop a simple game that teaches kindergartners how to add single-digit numbers. Your function `game()` will take an integer n as input and then ask n single-digit addition questions. The numbers to be added should be chosen randomly from the range [0,9] (i.e., 0 to 9 inclusive). The user will enter the answer when prompted. Your function should print “Correct” for correct answers and “Incorrect” for incorrect answers. After n questions, your function should print the number of correct answers.

For example:

```
>>>game(3)
8+2=
Enter answer: 10
Correct.
6+7 =
Enter answer: 12
Incorrect.
7+7=
Enter answer: 14
Correct.

You got 2 correct answers out of 3
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
def game(n):
  x = random.randrange (0,10)
  y = random.randrange(0,10)
  numbers = (x+y)
  print (x, "+", y)
  guess = eval(input("Enter your guess: "))
  count = 0
  total = 0
  while total <= n:
    if guess == numbers:
      count = count + 1
      total = total + 1
      print("Correct.")
      break
    elif guess != numbers:
      total = total + 1
      print("Inncorrect")
      break
  return ("You got" + sum(count) + "correct answers out of" + sum(total))
```

I can get to where it states whether the answer is correct or not but can't figure out how to get it to run n times and display the results.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues with the snippet shown, some functional, some pertaining to style and readability.

First, the reason why your `while` loop doesn't repeat is because of the `break` statements.  These cause the program to continue to the instruction following the while, i.e. they cause a "premature" exit from the while loop.

You will also need to place the guessing prompt etc. *inside* the loop...  As shown they will be executed once, before the loop and not for each iteration.

You do not need the `sum()` for count and total.

Now onto style issues:
**Edit**: I also would like to plug `Jon Clements`'s remark: AVOID `eval()`!
I ranted myself enough against `eval` in other SO postings, with reason: although there are a very few use cases where `eval()` is necessary, in most instances, there are much better alternatives to this relatively "dangerous" function. Here, use int() to get the user's input converted to an integer.

You may consider avoiding the repetition of the `total = total + 1` since that must be done in both cases, whether the answer is correct or incorrect.  (Also consider `for x in range(n)` loop instead, see below.)
Also replace the elif, by a plain `else` since the condition tested is the inverse of the 'if' condition. 
[as suggested by  `nneonneo`]: avoiding parenthesis where not needed (as in the assigment of numbers), the use of the `+=` operator (which avoids repeating the lvalue).

It would also be a good idea to change the loop to a `for total in range(n)` as this would completely save you from managing the total variable.  I refrained form this latter change to keep the spirit of your initial code.

```
total = 1
while total <= n:
    x = random.randrange(0,10)
    y = random.randrange(0,10)
    numbers = x + y
    print (x, "+", y)
    guess = eval(input("Enter your guess: "))
    total = total + 1
    if guess == numbers:
        count = count + 1
        print("Correct.")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
 print("You got", count, "correct answers out of", total)
```

Comment: (1) suggest you use `for total in range(n)`, (2) suggest you use `count += 1`, (3) suggest you remove the brackets around `x+y`. (We want to teach people good coding style, too!)

Comment: @nneonneo  thanks for the suggestions (and for fixing my print() statement ;-).   I kept the loop as is, with explicitly managed `total` variable as is.  You are right to teach good coding style early on, but it is also ok to let beginners use their explicit idioms and learn shortcut a bit later as their command of the programming language improves.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I was able to get the correct answer after using the above code and recommended alterations. The only thing is that I changed total = 1 to 0 and added count = 0.

Comment: Please don't use `eval` - use `int` instead for this case

Comment: I have to second.. Or third that. Don't use `eval`, especially on user input - that's like picking things off the ground and putting them in your mouth and expecting it to end well. Also @user2055337 if @mjv helped you, you should really accept his answer.